# On tumblr, how can I see the contact info. of the submitter after I approve a submitted post?

Tags: api, tumblr

I've started accepting tumblr submissions on my tumblr blog, and they arrive in the form of

> Submitter Name (submitter_email@example.com) submitted to MY-TUMBLR-BLOG-NAME:
>   [Content]

However, once I click "publish" on the submission, the name and e-mail address of the submitter is gone and my dashboard just says "Anonymous published to MY-TUMBLR-BLOG-NAME", and I have no way of figuring out who the original submitter was.

How do I find the original contact info. for the submitter after I accept their submission by publishing it?

Comment: Change your settings to receive an e-mail every time someone sends a submission and then archive the e-mails in your e-mail provider. That's going to be the only way that I can think of to solve your problem.